# Websocket client disconnect websocket4net

Tags: android, websocket, mono, websocket4net

I've been having random websocket disconnects.

My stack is:

- Monodroid
- Websocket4net
- Spring websockets

I'm not sure if anyone else has experienced this.

Usually the client will work perfectly and then randomly, it'll experience a disconnect. Any help or insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you send [Ping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) frames (or unsolicited [Pong](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.3) frames) periodically from the client to the server in order to keep the WebSocket connection? By default, many server implementations disconnect idle connections automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Websocket4Net has an auto ping feature.  Set EnableAutoSendPing and AutoSendPingInterval appropriately for your server.

https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net/blob/042ff279bfb5e9eabe3920452b372bf12c82636c/WebSocket4Net/WebSocket.cs#L38